# "NameError: name 'url' is not defined" の解決方法を教えてください

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium

Windows10, ANACONDA.NAVIGATOR から JupyterLab 3.0.14 を起動して、
"【Selenium】スクレイピング対策を突破する方法" サイトを参照して、コードをコピーペーストして実行した所、エラーが表示されました。
エラーを検索して解決を試みましたが、自身のスキル不足で解決できません。
ご教授お願いします。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)                 
<ipython-input-20-ed48c50edfbb> in <module>                 
----> 1 html = get_page_from_amazon(url)                    
                    
NameError: name 'url' is not defined
```

**ソースコード:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def get_page_from_amazon(url):
     
    text = ""
    #　ヘッドレスモードでブラウザを起動
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
     
    # ブラウザーを起動
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # 見つからないときは、10秒まで待つ
     
    text = driver.page_source
         
    # ブラウザ停止
    driver.quit()
     
    return text

html = get_page_from_amazon(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

html = get_page_from_amazon(url)
```

**参照サイトURL:**
[【Selenium】スクレイピング対策を突破する方法](https://teshi-learn.com/2020-08/selenium-scraping-regulation-breakthrough/?unapproved=25265&moderation-hash=dcf1ff87f4d91166866a421833dd6d71#comment-25265)

Answer (score 1):

エラーそのものはメッセージとして表示されている通り "`url` が定義されていない" のが原因なので、スクレイピング対象の URL を事前に定義するだけだと思います。

```py
url  = "https://amazon.co.jp/XXX/XXX/" # <- 追加
html = get_page_from_amazon(url)
```

エラーメッセージが英語の場合、まずは翻訳してみることをお勧めします。

機械翻訳結果(例):

> NameError：名前 'url'が定義されていません

---

ただし、質問で参照しているページのコードは、別のサイトのコードを参照したうえで必要な部分のみ修正して掲載している様にも見えるので、スクレイピングそのものが正しく動くのかは分かりません。

Comment: 早々のご丁寧なご助言、ありがとうございます。ご助言通り定義の上、実行しました所、新たなエラーが表示され…解決に取り組みたいと思います。